# How to fix 'ValueError: Empty Training Data' error in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I am new to tensorflow and keras. I am trying to train a model to identify different images for rock paper and scissors. I am using an online tutorial for that and they have provided me with a google collab worksheet. When I train the model on google collab everything works fine but if I try training the model on my machine, it gives me this error:
`ValueValueError: Empty training data`
I have tried changing the batch size and also tried tried changing the amount of images in the dataset but it doesnt help(And it shouldn't).

Here is my code:

```
###### ROCK PAPER SISSORS #######

import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import keras_preprocessing
from keras_preprocessing import image
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import matplotlib.image as mpimg


# Provide the path to the directory of the classes
rock_dir = os.path.join('/media/visheshchanana/New Volume/Projects/datasets/RPS/rps/rock')
paper_dir = '/media/visheshchanana/New Volume/Projects/datasets/RPS/rps/paper'
scissors_dir = '/media/visheshchanana/New Volume/Projects/datasets/RPS/rps/scissors'


rock_files = os.listdir(rock_dir)
# print(rock_files[:10])
#  ​
paper_files = os.listdir(paper_dir)
# print(paper_files[:10])
# ​
scissors_files = os.listdir(scissors_dir)
# # print(scissors_files[:10])



# Use the augmentation tool to change the augmentation of the images so that we can have a better classifier
TRAINING_DIR = "/media/visheshchanana/New Volume/Projects/datasets/RPS/rps"
training_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale = 1./255,
      rotation_range=40,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest')

# Provide the path to the validation dataset
VALIDATION_DIR = "/media/visheshchanana/New Volume/Projects/datasets/RPS/RPS_validation"
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

train_generator = training_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAINING_DIR,
    target_size=(150,150),
    class_mode='categorical'
)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    VALIDATION_DIR,
    target_size=(150,150),
    class_mode='categorical'
)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # Note the input shape is the desired size of the image 150x150 with 3 bytes color
    # This is the first convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    # The second convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # The third convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # The fourth convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # Flatten the results to feed into a DNN
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    # 512 neuron hidden layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])


model.summary()
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=5, validation_data = validation_generator, verbose = 1)
```

The dataset is the same as used in the google collab. I can't figure out the reason behind this error.

Comment: It sounds like your path to the dataset is incorrect. Did you update the paths to the dataset to reflect the path on your machine? You can likely copy the absolute path from the file itself and paste that directly into the code.

Comment: @wakeel the path is correct. It works well for almost 1 epoch and then throws this error. Also, I am able to plot the images.

Comment: I don't know whether this actually answers your question fully, but when I stumbled this question out of my own misery, I realized that I had a batch size that was greater than my sample size.
If it helps, I can make an answer, but until I am sure that it is a solution, I will let this be a comment for now.

Comment: @mehmet.ali.anil thanks man, this was my problem and it was driving me crazy!!! you should DEFINITELY make an answer

Comment: @pcko1 All right (: happy that it helped.

Answer (score 11):

There might be other reasons for this error, but I realized that I had a **batch size that was greater than my sample size**.

Comment: Thank you for this! I was having the same issue caused by batch_size being larger than my training samples. ie. `batch_size > train_feature.shape[0]`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. My model trains and gives this error (ValueValueError: Empty training data) at the end of the first epoch. I figured out that it was because there was no data in the validation path.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `steps_per_epoch` is not set to 0 (e.g. because of integer division)